# Execute SSIS Package Remotely C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

My web app pass a parameter to the SSIS package and executes it. Everything runs smooth on the development machine. But when i deploy the app to production server, the execution fails.

Error is "Failed to connect to server ."

It fails at the second line

```
 var ssisCon = new SqlConnection(connectString);
 var integrationSvc = new IntegrationServices(ssisCon);
```

Here is my connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SSISHOST" connectionString="Data Source=TESTSERVER\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Application on IIS runs under application pool using my credentials, so it can't be a permission issue, so if everything runs fine on my machine, how does it get broken after publishing.

I can't seem to figure out what is breaking the app, Is it the connection string? I can provide more information if someone needs.

Comment: What if you test the `State` of the ssisCon? I would think you're missing a call to `ssisCon.Open();` in there but as you say, it works on your machine.

Comment: Okay, i tested the state, and got this: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. So something is definitely wrong with the connection string itself, but hey i get no issues while running on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

**So the answer is: it is not possible, yet.**

You cannot run packages outside SQL Server Data Tools on a client computer that does not have Integration Services installed, and the terms of your SQL Server licensing might not let you install Integration Services on additional computers. Integration Services is a server component and is not redistributable to client computers.

My machine has Integration Services Installed but the production server doesn't have them. Hence i am able to run the app successfully on my machine. So crux is Integration Services and IIS needs to be on the same machine or both servers needs to have both the services.

**Very Helpful:** http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx

Comment: I'm confused by your final sentence:  Integration Services and IIS needs to be on the same machine or both servers needs to have both the services. You can have IIS installed on A, SQL Server 2012 + SSIS installed on B and start packages on B from A. You will need to use TSQL and the Project Deployment model to do so

Comment: Both sentences are correct, either Integration Services and IIS needs to be on the same computer OR both different servers need to have both services installed. If i only have IIS installed on A, and SSIS package on server B, i can't execute the package from web application in this scenario.

Comment: But you can execute packages remotely. 2012 makes this easy but it's still an option prior to the 2012 release of SQL Server. The MSDN article you linked showed how to stand up a web service for doing so but that is not required. You could create a classic Windows service, you can use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), SQL Agent or probably some other things that don't spring to mind.

Comment: in the MSDN article, Web Service still needs to be hosted on the same server as the package, and WebService needs IIS for hosting. So we reach the ground zero again. Yes, i agree with the other ways that you have mentioned.

Comment: Can't you call it from a proc, and then call the proc from the web app? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/658959/Execute-SSIS-Packge-by-using-Csharp-and-SQL-Server